# how to remove object in array by index mongodb / mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, body-parser

I'm new to web development, please be gentle :)

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    team: [
       [0] { name: '',
        department: '',
        role: '' },

       [1] { name: '',
        department: '',
        role: '' },

       [2] { name: '',
        department: '',
        role: '' }
        ],
    proposal: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Proposal"
    },
    techEvaluation: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "techEval"
    },
});
```

i'm trying to delete object by choice from team array.

```
router.post('/project/deleteTeamMember', (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body);
   Project.update(req.body.id, {$unset: {team: {name: req.body.tm}}}, {multi: true}, function (err, members) {
      if(err){
         res.send(err)
      }else{
         console.log(members);
         res.send(members)
      }
   });
});
```

I get the [index] of object that was clicked and pass it to route but can't use it to delete certain objects.

long story short, i wanna do something like this:

```
Project.update(req.body.id, {$delete: {team: [2] }}, {multi: true}
```

so it could delete third object from team array